# Sort file with respect to a part of a column

Tags: sed

I have one file that contains the details of space in data stores. I want to sort it according to the Free space available in them.

File is :

```
Name:VSP-01-32     Capacity:2047   Free Space:144
Name:VSP-02-33     Capacity:2047   Free Space:333
Name:VSP-03-34     Capacity:2047   Free Space:163
Name:VSP-04-35     Capacity:2047   Free Space:110
Name:VSP-05-36     Capacity:2047   Free Space:256
Name:VSP-06-37     Capacity:2047   Free Space:417
```

The output should look like:

```
Name:VSP-06-37     Capacity:2047   Free Space:417
Name:VSP-02-33     Capacity:2047   Free Space:333
Name:VSP-05-36     Capacity:2047   Free Space:256
Name:VSP-03-34     Capacity:2047   Free Space:163
Name:VSP-01-32     Capacity:2047   Free Space:144
Name:VSP-04-35     Capacity:2047   Free Space:110
```

I tried using sed and awk, but I couldn't find a convincing solution. Please help.

Comment: When you ask questions, there are some options to format it. You can use the code block, as I have, to make your question easier to read and render as you've typed them :)

Answer (score 4):

If you look at `man sort` you'll find that (GNU) sort lets you specify the field to sort by.  Try:

```
sort -n -t: -k4 -r
```

`-n` means sort numerically instead of lexicographically.

`-t:` tells it to use `:` to delimit (split) fields.

`-k4` tells it to use the fourth field.

`-r` tells it to reverse the result.

---

This has the caveat of not working when you have a `:` in the filename (which will shift the fields/columns). If that is a requirement, the easiest way to go would be a script (e.g. perl or python).

Comment: It is `-k4` instead of `-f4`. And he wants reverse order, so `-r` has to be applied, too.